# how to write an equation to make negative return -100% but not 0 and positive

Tags: math, equation, sign

I need to write an equation for my report, I want to covert all negative result to -100% but 0 and positive result remain the same.

Example:

```
result = sign((x-y)/total) when x<y
result = (x-y)/total when x>=y
```

Is there an elegant equation to represent this? Just one equation.

Thank you.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: there's no way to answer this without a language

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any other way to represent this equation. What you're trying to write, is a function with 2 branches. If you can't write your function on paper **inline**, there is no way to do it on a computer.